# Include only if a variable is not empty

Tags: c#, blazor

In my code FirstName and LastName always has values, but MiddleName does not always, so my question is how can I best create an additional string of concatenating the three variables, but not including MiddleName if MiddleName does not have a value.

Here's my code so far, but this is so long winded and I know can be simplified.

```
if (newContributor.MiddleName == "")
{
  newContributor.Url =
  newContributor.FirstName.Replace(" ", "-").ToLower() + "-" +
  newContributor.LastName.Replace(" ", "-").ToLower();
}
else
{
  newContributor.Url =
  newContributor.FirstName.Replace(" ", "-").ToLower() + "-" +
  newContributor.MiddleName.Replace(" ", "-").ToLower() + "-" +
  newContributor.LastName.Replace(" ", "-").ToLower();
}
```

What would you all suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not create a temporary `string` that you concatenate into and only add the `MiddleName` part if it's not empty? Or preferably do that with a `StringBuilder`. Such an approach gets rid of the code duplication

Answer (score 5):

```
string[] parts = { firstName, middleName, lastName };
url = string.Join('-', parts.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(p)))
   .ToLower()
   .Replace(' ', '-');
```

You can make that 1 statement but that's not very readable.

In addition, you may want to handle all other 'invalid' chars with

```
url = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);
```

Answer (score 2):

You said only the middle name will be null. I also like to test for white space so I have used `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

As a property in your class:

```cs
class Contributer
{
    ...
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string? MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Url => GetUrl();

    private string GetUrl() => GetHyphenatedName()
       .Replace(oldChar: ' ', newChar: '-')
       .ToLower();

    private string GetHyphenatedName() => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MiddleName) ?
            $"{FirstName}-{LastName}" :
            $"{FirstName}-{MiddleName}-{LastName}";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one

```
newContributor.Url=[firstName,middleName,lastName ]
                    .filter(p=>p)
                    .join("-")
                    .replace(" ","-")
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman, sorry, I thought that was a question about javascript (typescript)

Answer (score 0):

```
string url = (firstName + (middleName != "" ? "-" + middleName : "") + "-" + lastName)
    .Replace(" ", "-")
    .ToLower();
```

or

```
string url = string.Join('-', new[] {firstName, middleName, lastName}.Where(p => p != ""))
    .Replace(" ", "-")
    .ToLower();
```